# What exactly constitutes a nested set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To my understanding, a nested set is basically just a set where members are all members are subsets of the largest member. For example, take the set $\mathcal{S} = \{(\frac{1}{n},n+1)|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. As $n$ increases, the left moves more left and the right moves more right. Therefore, every interval $I_n \subset I_{n+1}$. So $\mathcal{S}$ is a nested set, right? Does this also go both ways? That is, if our set is now $\mathcal{R} = (n, \infty)| n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $I_{n+1} \subset I_n$ is this also a nested set? If so, what is an example of a non-nested set? I feel like every interval set I can think of either contains all its subsets or is contained in all its subsets.

Comment: $\{(n,n+1):n\in\Bbb N\}$ is as far from being nested as you can get: its members are pairwise disjoint. More interesting: $$\left\{\left(-\frac1n,n\right):n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Wow...such a simple example eluded me. So does that mean that a nested set indeed works both ways (i.e. $I_n \subset I_{n+1}$ and $I_n \supset I_{n+1}$ are both nested sets?

Comment: Yes, you can have both increasing and decreasing nests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A collection $\scr{S}$ of sets is said to be *nested* iff for every $A, B \in \scr{S},$ either $A\subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A.$ (Often you'll see $\scr{S}$$=\lbrace A_0, A_1, A_2, \dots \rbrace$ with either $A_0 \subseteq A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \dots$ or $A_0 \supseteq A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq\dots,$ but some nested collections have a more complicated structure than those.)

This is *not* the same thing as saying that all members of $\scr{S}$ are subsets of the largest member (if there even is a largest member).

Think of matryoshka dolls, which you've probably seen — Russian nested dolls, each one (except for the largest) contained in the next larger one, and each one (except for the smallest) containing the next smaller one.  (With infinite sets, there may not always be a next larger, or next smaller, one, even for sets in the "middle".  But any finite subset of $\scr{S}$ looks like a set of Russian dolls.)

Comment: So the term "nested" is interchangeably used for both the directions of nesting?

Comment: @mattecapu I want to say yes, except that you can’t necessarily even assign an overall “direction”.