# Name for a family of sets that all share a subset-superset relationship with each other?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Is there a name for a family of sets that are all related by a subset-superset relationship? i.e. for any two sets in the family, their intersection is equal to at least one of them?

Comment: This sets are called totally ordered sets.

Comment: “Totally ordered” can refer to any relation, not just the subset/superset relation. @Dbchatto67

Comment: But the sets which OP mentioned is also a special kind of totally ordered set where inclusion gives the ordering.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Yes, that’s true. It’s totally ordered by the inclusion relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s called a nested family of sets. See this answer for more information: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1956996

Comment: That's funny - I assumed there was a name, but if there hadn't been, I was going to call it a matryoshka family.